# Div vertical alignment not working on Chrome - works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fixing some existing code, the two divs align ok on Firefix/IE but NOT on Chrome.
Have tried playing with padding, though fixing it on Chrome then it breaks elsewhere.
Might me a simple overlooked settings that I can't seem to fix for days now.
Code:  (works fine, on firefox and not so well on chrome)
Any tips of fixing this?

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {}

  .autocomplete {
    /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  @media (max-width: 680px) {
    .autocomplete {
      /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70% !important;
    }
  }

  input {
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-radius: 25px 1px 1px 25px;
    display: inline-block;

  }

  @media (max-width: 680px) {
    input[type=text] {
      border: 20px solid transparent;
      border-left: 0px solid transparent;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;

      margin-left: 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 25px 1px 1px 25px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type=submit] {}
  }

  input[type=text] {
    background-color: #F4F7FA;
    width: 100%;
    border: 21px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  }

  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #ef7023;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
</style>

<div style="padding-top:60px;background-color:grey;">

  <form style="padding-left:33%;padding-right:30%;">
    <div class="autocomplete" style=" max-width:67%;width:100%;">

      <input class="search" type="text">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">

      <input value="" style="width:100px; max-width:100%;" type="submit"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: link to code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJJarJ

Comment: I have same result in chrome as in firefox

Comment: Try using `float` instead of `inline-block` : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjjzJE

Comment: you have problem in firefox also. I wrote a solution as an answer.

Comment: @V.Sambor I should mention on desktop, maybe you checked on mobile?

Comment: @SujataChanda - there still seems to be a small offset on firefox, while chrome looks good. Is there a reason why the offset (search field is wider then orange input) ?

Answer (score 0):

For `inline-block` elements you should add `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to your element for vertical alignment.

add this to your css :

```
form {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

I set value `50px` but you can set appropriate value by yourself.

Also remove `padding-top: 60px` from your main `div`.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {}

  .autocomplete {
    /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  @media (max-width: 680px) {
    .autocomplete {
      /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70% !important;
    }
  }

  input {
    border: 21px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 25px 1px 1px 25px;
    display: inline-block;

  }

  @media (max-width: 680px) {
    input[type=text] {
      border: 20px solid transparent;
      border-left: 0px solid transparent;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;

      margin-left: 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-radius: 25px 1px 1px 25px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type=submit] {}
  }

  input[type=text] {
    background-color: #F4F7FA;
    width: 100%;
    border: 21px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  }

  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #ef7023;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px 25px 25px 1px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100% !important;
  }

form {
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}
</style>

<div style="background-color:grey;">

  <form>
    <div class="autocomplete" style=" max-width:67%;width:100%;">

      <input class="search" type="text">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">

      <input value="" style="width:100px; max-width:100%;" type="submit"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is a complete guide to center elements vertically and horizontally : [centering elements complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: when I run your snippet they don't seem aligned?

Comment: if you consider gray area, input is vertically aligned. you can increase or decrease `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to achieve appropriate result.